# How to avoid centos-release rpm installing yum repo files via spacewalk

Tags: centos, rpm, yum, repo

We have a Spacewalk server we use to distribute updates to our CentOS 6 and 7 client systems. None of the client systems have internet access. Only the spacewalk server has restricted access to complete repo sync updates.

We have an issue when it comes time to push out the centos-release rpms. this rpm installs repo config files like /etc/yum.repo.d/CentOS-Base.repo. Since the client system can't get out to the internet, any subsequent yum command displays an error about not enough mirrors.

Does any one know of a way to have either Spacewalk or yum exclude the /etc/yum.repos.d/ directory on install of the centos-release package.

It has to be an automated or configurable method as I currently run a manual command on each of the affected systems when I know that rpm is being pushed out. (/bin/rm /etc/yum.repo.d/CentOS-*.repo). I considered a cron job, but that just didn't seem like the best option.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell yum **not** to use a certain repository:

```
yum install --disablerepo=centos-base
```

or you can tell him to only use your repository by disabling all others:

```
yum install --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=myrepo
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have seen in the past is to configure yum to *not* use the default location, but instead a different one. For example, `/etc/yum.internal.repos.d/`. Then anything that happens in the default location doesn't matter.